# invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]; VTK-7.1.1 compilation error

Tags: c++, vtk

As the title says, I'm not a c++ programmer, I'm just trying to compile this so I can compile some modules for FreeCAD that I would like.  I had problems with VTK-8.90 I couldn't figure out so I'm trying this version because it is the recommended stable version for the modules. Not being a programmer and googling this error a bunch, I played around a lot with removing and adding/removing various "const" and "char*" to the indicated errors- but I really don't know what I'm doing so I thought I'd try to get a specific answer. (I don't think the source code as written is necessarily the problem.)  I'm compiling to use it with python3.7, the default is 2.7, but this shouldn't matter right because this is c++ code?

This is the error specifically:

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object Wrapping/PythonCore/CMakeFiles/vtkWrappingPythonCore.dir/vtkPythonArgs.cxx.o
/src/VTK-7.1.1/Wrapping/PythonCore/vtkPythonArgs.cxx: In instantiation of ‘bool vtkPythonGetStringValue(PyObject*, T*&, const char*) [with T = char; PyObject = _object]’:
/src/VTK-7.1.1/Wrapping/PythonCore/vtkPythonArgs.cxx:287:66:   required from here
/src/VTK-7.1.1/Wrapping/PythonCore/vtkPythonArgs.cxx:105:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
     a = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(o);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
make[2]: *** [Wrapping/PythonCore/CMakeFiles/vtkWrappingPythonCore.dir/build.make:63: Wrapping/PythonCore/CMakeFiles/vtkWrappingPythonCore.dir/vtkPythonArgs.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9917: Wrapping/PythonCore/CMakeFiles/vtkWrappingPythonCore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

And this is the first referenced section of vtkPythonArgs.cxx (starting from line 93):

```
template <class T> inline
bool vtkPythonGetStringValue(PyObject *o, T *&a, const char *exctext)
{
  if (PyBytes_Check(o))
  {
    a = PyBytes_AS_STRING(o);
    return true;
  }
#ifdef Py_USING_UNICODE
  else if (PyUnicode_Check(o))
  {
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03030000
    a = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(o);
    return true;
#else
    PyObject *s = _PyUnicode_AsDefaultEncodedString(o, NULL);
    if (s)
    {
      a = PyBytes_AS_STRING(s);
      return true;
    }

    exctext = "(unicode conversion error)";
#endif
  }
#endif

  PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, exctext);
  return false;
}

inline bool vtkPythonGetStdStringValue(PyObject *o, std::string &a, const char *exctext)
{
  if (PyBytes_Check(o))
  {
    char* val;
    Py_ssize_t len;
    PyBytes_AsStringAndSize(o, &val, &len);
    a = std::string(val, len);
    return true;
  }
#ifdef Py_USING_UNICODE
  else if (PyUnicode_Check(o))
  {
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03030000
    Py_ssize_t len;
    const char* val = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(o, &len);
    a = std::string(val, len);
    return true;
#else
    PyObject *s = _PyUnicode_AsDefaultEncodedString(o, NULL);
    if (s)
    {
      char* val;
      Py_ssize_t len;
      PyBytes_AsStringAndSize(s, &val, &len);
      a = std::string(val, len);
      return true;
    }

    exctext = "(unicode conversion error)";
#endif
  }
#endif

  PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, exctext);
  return false;
}
```

Line 287 (starting from 281):

```
inline
bool vtkPythonGetValue(PyObject *o, char *&a)
{
  a = NULL;

  return (o == Py_None ||
          vtkPythonGetStringValue(o, a, "string or None required"));
}
```

The file is 1600 lines, I'm not sure if the whole thing would be more help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a [mcve] where you just use that function that causes the error, in a hello world type c++ app, with the python.h included, of course. On a possibly unrelated note, the python version matters. You want the include and lib from that installation when you build this python module in c++.

Comment: thanks for that link and the tips, I will investigate and try your suggestion. I'm always trying to improve my questions, I always die a little on the inside when my post gets the immediate down vote. (Also, I verified in my CMakeCache.txt that it the proper python 3.7 includes and libs are being referenced.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like the function `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` must be returning a `char const*`. The function `vtkPythonGetValue` calls the template function `vtkPythonGetStringValue`. `vtkPythonGetValue` takes as parameter `a`, an lvalue reference to non-const pointer to non-const `char` and passes it along to `vtkPythonGetStringValue`, causing it to get instantiated with `T` deduced to `char` instead of `char const`. A pointer to const object cannot be assigned to a pointer to non-const, only the reverse is allowed. So the function `vtkPythonGetValue` should really be taking an lvalue reference to non-const pointer to const `char`. Like so:

```
inline
bool vtkPythonGetValue(PyObject* o, char const*& a)
{
  a = NULL;
  return (o == Py_None ||
          vtkPythonGetStringValue(o, a, "string or None required"));
}
```

Comment: victory. sort of. your suggestion led to a different set of errors with the "definitions of the GetValue methods in the class"  i commented both out and it was able to compile.

Comment: well never mind, my commenting out made the library unlinkable at the end of compilation. duh.